# extendBody: true, property moves

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to recreate the main page of Spotify. At first I wasn't able to make my navigation bar transparent then I learned that I should use extendBody: true property. It worked and I got a transparent navigation bar but now it seems like it changed the space between the items on the screen and I am clueless at this point. This is the part where I added extendBody property:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF212121),
        title: Text("Spotify", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_outlined)),
          IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.history)),
          IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.settings)),
        ],
      ),
```

And this is the part that forms gridlist and the problematic part:

```
FutureBuilder<List<GridListe>>(
                future: gridListeyiGetir(),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    var gridListe = snapshot.data;
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: gridListe!.length,
                          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 3/1),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index){
                          var list = gridListe[index];
                          return Card(

                            semanticContainer: true,
                            color: Color(0xFF535353),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Image.asset("resimler/${list.listeResmi}", fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                                  child: Text(list.listeAdi, style:TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'Work Sans' ,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold) , ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                          }
                      ),
                    );
                  }else{
                    return const Center();
                  }
                },
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 280),
                child: const Text("Made For You", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Work Sans',fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
              ),


              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 180,
                  child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 160,
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 0,
                          color: Color(0xFF212121),
                          child:
                          Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset("resimler/dailymix1.jpg"),
                              Text("Daily Mix 1", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "Work Sans", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

As can be seen in the images the grid list and "Made For You" text should be somewhat close to eachother however its not the case.

**when extendBody:false**

[image]

**when extendBody:true**

[image]

Comment: You should add the part of your code that generates the buggy part. As it stands, we can't really tell. I can guess that you have a column that wraps your home page area widgets. I'm guessing that because if the Column stretches to the height of the page, and extendBody extends it, there will be more space for it, and the alignment might not be what you want. Maybe you can play with `mainAxisSize` or `mainAxisAlignment`/`crossAxisAlignment` if that's the case

Comment: could you please include the full code of your first screen that contain that grid view?

Comment: okay I editted my question, thank you.